Metal flashing under drywall around window?
What is this metal around the window? It's under the drywall on all four sides. It looks like flashing but it's inside, so that doesn't really make sense. The original window was installed with clips, what looks like metal flashing on top, then the drywall.
We're getting new windows installed. The installer says this metal isn't important. It was an old way to install.
It's not old corner bead, it's under the drywall. The house is 20 years old.
I'm not convinced. Our house is on a beach in the north Atlantic and gets battered with extraordinarily high winds.
Any idea on what the metal is?





Looks more like reinforcement for high winds to me, but I'm sure there's someone here that can answer it more definitively.

Protip: Touch your phone's screen on the subject to adjust exposure. Then the stuff we need to see won't be in the dark.

I don't know for sure either, but it just looks like internal flanges to me. I agree with your installer.

Thanks for all the input. What is the purpose of internal flanges?

The galvanized metal are window anchor straps.
Instead of fasteners through the frame and into the rough stud or using an exterior flange and fitting the window with exposed fasteners through the outside wall, they screw a strap to the backside of the window frame that lets the installer fit the window without exposed fasteners.
The internal painted metal shapes are jamb extensions to provide support for the drywall.

Thanks, I know the straps are needed (first pic, strap/clip on the upper right). It's the bent metal  flashing installed over the straps that are unclear. For example, if you were getting windows replaced, would want the same two layers of metal: straps/clips + metal flashing on top. Many thanks

The flashing in the first picture pointing to the left. Are these anchored to the window and the inside face of the stud? What did you remove in order to expose this flashing?

Yes. Drywall was removed to expose this flashing. I added a pic of this flashing removed. It has a 'Z' shape.

Updated my answer.

Many thx. If it were your house, would you require the jamb extensions to be replaced with the new window install? And, what happens if they aren't put in?

This is an aesthetic question. They are not required for the window installation itself. If you want the interior of the window to appear larger or if you want to instead frame them with wood with perhaps a molding around the interior perimeter opening, then you leave them off.

Many thx. The agreement with the installer is to return the drywall to it's original condition. My takeaway: these are needed

Is there any reason to choose metal over SPF/plywood? I heard from my installer they want to use SPF or plywood as the jamb extension instead of metal (to better fill voids and I believe because it's cheaper). If we want metal (on top of the SPF), we have to pay extra. I understand that metal may better prevent cracking but I have no experience to confirm if that's the case. Thoughts?

Jamb extensions are used to solve a detailing problem that should have been specified at the beginning of the project. Now that the project is underway, solving the problem to the satisfaction of both parties is the best way forward.
